# Border line around a group of certain countries in a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, plotly

I'm plotting a Europe map as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(rworldmap)

## Get the world map: ##
worldMap <- getMap()

## Define vector with all European countries: ##
v.europe <- c("Norway", "Sweden", "Finland", "Denmark", "United Kingdom","Ireland", "Greece",
              "Belgium", "Netherlands", "France", "Spain", "Portugal", "Luxembourg", "Croatia",
              "Germany", "Switzerland", "Austria", "Slovenia", "Italy", "Bulgaria", "Romania",
              "Czech Rep.", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Poland", "Bosnia Hercegovina", "Serbia",
              "Turkey", "Ukraine", "Moldova", "Belarus", "Estonia", "Latvia", "Lithuania",
              "Montenegro", "Albania", "Macedonia")

## Select only the index of countries of Europe: ##
indEU <- which(worldMap$NAME%in%v.europe)


## Extract longitude and latitude border's coordinates of countries: ##
df.europeCoords <- lapply(indEU, function(i){
  df <- data.frame(worldMap@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
  df$region = as.character(worldMap$NAME[i])
  colnames(df) <- list("long", "lat", "region")
  return(df)
})
df.europeCoords <- do.call("rbind", df.europeCoords)
names(df.europeCoords) <- c("longitude", "latitude", "country")

## Deletes/Removes borders of PLOT: ##
ax <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = FALSE,
  showgrid = FALSE
)

## Plot the map: ##
p <- ggplot(data = df.europeCoords, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group = country, 
                                        text = paste("<b>", country, '</b>\n')), 
            color = "grey50", size = 0.1) + 
     geom_polygon() +
     coord_map(xlim = c(-13, 35),  ylim = c(32, 71)) +
     theme_classic() +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
           axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
           plot.margin = unit(0 * c(-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5), "lines"))

## Create plot_ly() object: ##
EuropePlot <- plotly::ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>%
              layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax)
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]

I would like to draw a **red** border around **a group of countries**. This group should include the following countries: Austria, Germany, Denmark, Belgium, France and Switzerland. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to do this is to create a new column in your data frame which acts as a flag for which countries should be colored red:

```r
df.europeCoords$red <- df.europeCoords$country %in% 
  c("Austria", "Germany", "Denmark", "Belgium", "France", "Switzerland")
```

Now you map this variable to the color aesthetic, specifying `NA` outline color for the countries that are `FALSE` in column `red`, and specifying `"red"` for the countries that have the value `TRUE`:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df.europeCoords, 
            aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group = country, 
                text = paste("<b>", country, '</b>\n')),
            color = "grey50", size = 0.1) + 
     geom_polygon(aes(color = red), size = 1) +
     scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "red")) +
     coord_map(xlim = c(-13, 35),  ylim = c(32, 71)) +
     theme_classic() +
     theme(axis.text.x  = element_blank(), 
           axis.text.y  = element_blank(), 
           axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
           axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
           axis.title   = element_blank(), 
           legend.position = "none",
           plot.margin = unit(0 * c(-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5), "lines"))

p
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to erase the inner boundaries with your version? So that the border line is only drawn around a group of countries, like the answer below your answer. The package ```sf``` shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to draw a red border around a group of countries. This can be easily achieved by using sf::st_union().

Create plot with red borders around certain countries:

```r
  library(tidyverse)
  library(spatialrisk)
  library(sf)  

  red_borders <- spatialrisk::europe_countries %>%
    filter(admin %in% c("Austria", "Germany", "Denmark", 
                        "Belgium", "France", "Switzerland"))

  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = spatialrisk::europe_countries) +
    geom_sf(data = red_borders, color = "red") +
    theme_void()
```

[image]

Or remove internal boundaries in sf-object:

```r
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = spatialrisk::europe_countries) +
    geom_sf(data = sf::st_union(red_borders), color = "red", alpha = 0) +
    theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Would this also be possible without the ```sf``` package, as with the code above?

Comment: st_union comes from the sf package, this can not be done in base R. What is the reason that you don’t want to use the sf package?

Comment: I have a problem/error with this package, and I have already done so much without this package (my own plot is already very developed, here with the question I only mentioned a basic plot.). So I would prefer the base way. But I'll try to mix the ```st.union``` with my already developed plot.

Comment: Unfortunately, ```sf.union```doesn't work in combination with my plot!

Comment: You can use the fill argument: geom_sf(data = red_borders, fill = "red"). Does this solve the problem?

Comment: unfortunately, not